# PyQt Input Multiple Values in One Line

Tags: python, pyqt

I want the user to input a series of values separated by blanks (or commas) in one text edit or any other input widget in PyQt. then I would like to be able to use these values in calculations. Please see the picture which gives an example to what I am trying to do.

[image: Example picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the idea is to use a QLineEdit and to prevent the user from entering inappropriate values using a QRegExpValidator, for example assuming that you only want floating values to be entered, the following example only allows entering that type of values, spaces and commas by calculating the sum and showing the values in a QListWidget:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)

        regex = r"^(\s*(-|\+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*,\s*)+(-|\+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*$"
        validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(QtCore.QRegExp(regex), self)
        self._le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self._le.setValidator(validator)

        self._list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self._result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        flay.addRow("Input: ", self._le)
        flay.addRow("Output: ", self._list_widget)
        flay.addRow("Sum of values: ", self._result_label)
        flay.addRow(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        self._list_widget.clear()
        if self._le.text():
            values = [float(val) for val in self._le.text().split(",")]
            print(values)
            self._list_widget.addItems([str(val) for val in values])
            self._result_label.setText(str(sum(values)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]